# Setting class of lightning-input to slds-theme_error seems to disable it

Tags: lightning-design-system

After setting the class of lightning-input to slds-theme_error, it seems like the input element has been disabled: clicking inside the element puts the focus on it, but no cursor appears and typing seems ineffective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not what it seems, the input element is enabled and active.

The thing is that the slds-theme_error class not only sets the background color (as stated in the [documentation](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/themes/)), it also changes the text color. But the theme has some strange effects on a lightning-input element:

First, only the background of the surroundings (which includes the label) of the lightning-element is affected, not of the lightning-element itself, that remains white.

Second, the text color of the label and the text inside the lightning-input element are affected differently: the label's text color is still black, but the text color of the text inside the lightning-input changes to white. Which makes the text inside the lightning-input invisible. Which explains the observed behavior.

[image]